# how to create Vue pluggable components

Tags: vue.js, plugins, vue-component

I want to create an application with a plugin structure. I figured out that the best way would be compiling plugins as web components and then use them, but importing them not as global components appeared to be difficult. So, what is the best way to import and use external Vue component? I don't want to make component global, because I would like to unload plugins when the user turns them off.

Comment: I have the same question. As far as I came, maybe [scaleApp](http://scaleapp.org/) is a possibility. But I donÄt know how to combine it with Vue yet.